# Troubleshooting debian 7 network config

Tags: linux-networking

I'm setting up a proxmox host, to manage a couple VMs, but I'm having problems with the network configuration.
After install, I ended up with a bridged configuration that worked well for the VMs, but the host could not reach the internet.
I could ping other machines on the lan (my laptop), but could't ping the router (?!?!).

I decided to reconfigure from scratch, and a simple dhcp configuration did get me internet connection:

/etc/network/interfaces

```
########################
auto lo
iface eth0 inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
########################
```

building on this, I tried to setup a static IP:

/etc/network/interfaces

```
#########################
auto lo
iface eth0 inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.168.1.253
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 192.168.1.254
#########################
```

and I'm back at square 1, pinging my laptop (192.168.1.67) and no luck on the router (192.168.1.254)!

How can I troubleshoot this config?
I'm a programmer, my systems experience comes at bursts, when I need something done, so I can use some help on how to get the info you will probably ask me to show... :)

thanks

SOLVED!!
It was as stupid as having another device with the IP of the server! (still need to find out what device it is...)

Comment: It would be great it if you would post your solution as an answer and [mark it accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was trying to assign to the server an IP address that was already in use on my LAN